# Changing the colour palette

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to obtain a greater variety of colours in the lines/points on this scatterplot:

[image]

```
require(ggplot2)
dt.gg <- read.csv("http://goo.gl/5yjEZ")
dt.gg$X <- NULL
dt.gg$X.1 <- NULL

ggplot(dt.gg, aes(x=base, y=pred, color=hospital,group=hospital)) + geom_point(shape=1) +
 geom_line()+ theme(legend.position="none") + scale_fill_brewer(palette=3)
```

`scale_fill_brewer` doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try: `scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rainbow(7))`. You have too many groups. `scale_colour_brewer()` won't therefore work, I guess.

Comment: Nice. That works nicely. Please make it into an answer and I will accept it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rainbow(7))`.

Comment: or ´scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rainbow(7))´ what does the 7 stand for?

Comment: the number of colours to output. try `rainbow(1)`, `rainbow(2)` etc.. to see the difference.

Comment: I see thanks. I didn't have 7 objects to be able to see the difference. I found `scale_fill_brewer('palette'="Set3")` to be quite good too.